# Developing an intuition for compact and open sets

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

I'm having trouble picturing what compact sets and open sets actually are. Open and closed intervals make enough sense to me, but for whatever reason, moving to the next level of abstraction is difficult for me.

I've read the definition in my textbook (Ross), but it didn't help as much as I would like.

Comment: Open sets $O\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ are simple: for each point in the set, there is a ball around this point that $O$ contains - in other words, there is no "border".

Comment: Intuitively, a closed set is a set which contains its own boundary. Also, in some sense, a compact set is finite (all sequences of points have convergent subsequences).

Comment: How could one go about showing that a set is open? And what would be some examples of open sets?

Comment: Take a point in the set, show that that there is an small enough ball around this point that is contained in the set. The unit disc is $\mathbb{R}^2$ is open - you can draw this and verify that around each point you can draw a small enough 'cirlce'.

Comment: I like to think open sets are sets with some space and some degree of movement. Closed sets you pretty much can't get out, as there is not much "room".

Comment: @mathse, I'm not really seeing what you mean. How can I draw a small circle around the boundary points of the unit disk and stay within the disk?

Comment: @mathse is talking about the *open* unit disc: the set of points *inside* the unit circle but not including the unit circle itself.

Answer (score 2):

In the beginning it is always hard to understand these concepts, since they seem to lack  the motivation. Don't worry you'll get the hang of it. The best way to learn mathematics is by doing it. Don't just sit around and think about these concepts, try to apply them. Try and solve a problem on your own, doesn't matter if it takes weeks, that's the only way you'll ever  learn.

I found these videos on Youtube, which I think are quite useful. [This one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeVA74yivyg)  is particularly on Compact Sets. [The whole lecture series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqEyWLGvvdw&list=PL0E754696F72137EC) is amazing. I think he talks about open sets at around Lecture 8 or 9.

Comment: Thanks for the link - I watched his videos earlier in my course, I don't know why I didn't think of him.

Answer (score 0):

Properties of a topological space such as Hausdorff, regular, normal, *etc.* require that there be lots of open sets in the space. Compactness requires that there not be too many open sets in the space. (Example: with the discrete topology, where every point is an open set, an infinite space can't be compact.) These properties "fight" each other. So a compact Hausdorff space has a delicate balance of not too few and not too many open sets.

Answer (score 0):

The open subsets of the line do include the open intervals, but they also include sets that are the union of two open intervals, three open intervals, or even the union of an arbitrary collection of disjoint open intervals.

e.g. the set of all real numbers that are not integers is an open set.

The open intervals form a *basis* for the topology: you can detect whether or not a set $S$ is open by checking, for every point $x$, that there is an open interval $I$ such that $x \in I \subseteq S$.

Many topologies can be expressed in terms of a basis: in the plane, a common choice of basis is to let the basis open sets be the interiors of circles. Note that this doesn't mean all open sets look like circles: e.g. the set of points inside of a square forms an open set (because every point is contained in a circle that is contained entirely within the square).

---

If you're algebraically inclined, it's worth noting that if $f$ is a continuous real-valued function on a topological space, then the solution set to an inequation $a < f(x) < b$ always forms an open set. Also, the solution set to an inequation $a \leq f(x) \leq b$ always forms a closed set. ($a$ and $b$ are allowed to be $\pm \infty$)

Compact sets tell us something in the opposite direction: if $S$ is a compact set and $f$ is a continuous real-valued function, then $f(S)$ is also a compact set. (in the real line, the compact sets are the sets that are closed and bounded)